# Is that because Clojure is limited by JVM so this code can't evaluate?

Tags: clojure

code include something like `'(1+2)` in Clojure will cause a `java.lang.RuntimeException`, which leaves a error message "Unmatched delimiter: )".

But in any other lisp dialect I've ever used like Emacs Lisp or Racket, `'(1+2)` will just return a list, which **should** act like this because with the special form quote, anything in the list should not be evaluate.

So I just wonder is that because of the limitation of JVM so these codes can't act like how they act in other dialects? Or is it a bug of Clojure? Or maybe there is something different between the definition of quote in Clojure and other lisp dialects?

Comment: The actual error is `NumberFormatException Invalid number: 1+2  clojure.lang.LispReader.readNumber (LispReader.java:330)`. This is because clojure is trying (and failing) to read a number. The Unmatched delimiter error comes afterwards as a result of trying to read the rest of the expression.

Comment: I don't see how you would tie this behavior to the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

These are artifacts of the way tokenizers are set in different languages. In Clojure, if a token starts with a digit, it is consumed until the next reader macro character (that includes parentheses among other things,) whitespace or end of file (whitespace includes comma.) And what's consumed must be a valid number, which includes integer, float and rational. So when you feed `'(1+2)` to the reader, it consumes `1+2` as one token, which then fails to match against integer, float or rational number patterns. After that, the reader tries to recover, which resets its state. In this state, a `)` is unmatched.

Try to enter `'(1 + 2)` instead (mind the spaces around `+`,) you will see exactly what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So Clojure will always try to parse each element and convert them into some java objects(integer,string,etc) first, even when the list is quoted,instead of just treating them as symbols?

Comment: *Each* language processor must first parse its input. How do you expect Clojure or any other Lisp to understand that you have a quoted list without parsing the expression first? Second thing to point out, **unevaluated** does not mean **unparsed**. The word evaluation in Lisp has a precise sense - it's invoking a function, macro or special form in the head position. That is certainly prevented by a `quote` - in Clojure like in any Lisp. Clojure is a Lisp, and for instance much closer to Scheme than elisp is. You are looking for differences in a wrong place.

Comment: I *think* it would be roughly equivalent to say: in clojure, stuff inside quoted forms is *read*, but not *evaluated* --- and the reader doesn't know what to do with `1+2` -- it isn't a valid symbol (symbols can't start with numeric characters), keyword, number, etc.

Comment: @PaulGowder - no, the reader fails to *read* the form. In any Lisp, the reader never interprets the form, it just reads it. To be read, it must be well-formed. To be well-formed, it must be properly tokenized first, but the reader fails to tokenize `1+2`, it is an invalid **token**, not a number, not a symbol - it matches nothing in the grammar. This part is language dependent - as I said, the way tokenizers are set differs between languages. But what is not language dependent is the fact that the input must tokenize first before one can talk about reading and subsequent evaluation.

Comment: hmm... this is very interesting. Yuri, you clearly understand how lisps in general work better than I do --- what do you see as the difference between tokenization and reading?

Comment: Input `(1(` will properly tokenize to `(`, `1` and `(`, but the reader will still fail since it is ill-formed. I am not trying to nit pick (at least certainly not on you,) but the OP's misunderstanding is related to exactly this area - how the input stream of characters is broken down into tokens, and then the tokens are assembled into forms - and all that before the eval kicks in. The OP thinks in terms of semantic difference between Lisps, while what is shown is the difference on the low level of how tokens are recognized.

Comment: @PaulGowder - additionally: *everything* the reader successfully reads in the REPL is immediately evaluated, be that quoted or not. It's just the quoted form is translated by the reader into say `(quote (1 + 2))` which then immediately evaluates by invoking a special form `quote` which just returns it's argument *unevaluated*. That's how it works in any Lisp.

Comment: Ah,I think I see what mistake I have made.Thanks for the explanation.